# How to post-process django settings

Tags: django

I want to do some post-processing of a custom setting in my django project's settings.py file. In other words, I want to look at the value for this particular setting and then derive some additional values from it, which I can use later on, in a view, for instance.

I could do this post processing in the view, but then it needs to be done every time the view is called. I'd rather do it once when the application starts (or is restarted due to settings change).

I tried putting it in the __init__.py file of the relevant app, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from django.conf import settings

print settings.MY_CUSTOM_SETTING
```

But it bombs, saying there's no such attribute in settings.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, turns out I just need to define the setting further up in my settings.py file, before loading the application that wants to use it.